# Moment format returns invalid date

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

i have a date which i formated using moment to be shown like this:
03/04/2105. I want to transform it to iso using moment again. As a result i'm writing:

```
const IsoDateTo = moment(dateTo).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss');
```

The date to is 23/04/2105 but the IsoDateTo is returning something like this:
2105-03-04T00:00:00 Also when i enter a date greater than 12 it returns me Invalid Date. Why is this happening?

Comment: so... what is the "dateTo". is it a string or a moment object?

Comment: When i console.log the type of dateTo it shows a string. But to convert it to this string i use moment

Comment: *What* string? What is a "date greater than 9"?

Comment: When the day value is greater than 12 sorry not from 9 it shows me invalid date

Comment: you know that in different countries/locales the format of date differs. dd.mm.yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy, right? So for us locale month is coming first

Answer (score 72, accepted):

To make sure that you are correctly parsing the string you want to pass the expected string format along to the momentjs (something like this):

```
const IsoDateTo = moment(dateTo,'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score 7):

You cannot just throw any date format into it and expect it to magically recognize the format. Moment.js relies on the date parsing functionality of JavaScript if you do not specify and other format. According to the [MDN specification of Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), "dateString" can be either IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps or a version of ISO8601. Your date string is neither of it.

It is usually the best to use a date format like `YYYY-MM-DD`.

```
const IsoDateTo = moment('2105-03-04').format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss');
```